# How do I consume and display a DCAT file on DKAN

Tags: dkan, dcat

I would like to use DKAN to consume a DCAT file containing a data catalog and display it on the UI but am not sure how to do this or where instructions to do this are documented.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to consume DCAT to create a data visualization or consume DCAT metadata to import datasets?

Either way DKAN doesn't currently support that, however if we understand the use case it may be something we can add to the roadmap. There is an open issue for harvesting DCAT metadata as datasets into DKAN here: https://github.com/GetDKAN/dkan/issues/868 . If you can comment on that issue with your use case that would be very helpful. We create our roadmap based off of community feedback so would like to hear from you.

Comment: We have converted metadata from AWS data catalogs into DCAT and were hoping that we could consume/ingest that into DKAN to create what I suppose you are calling a data visualization.